# AWS Appsync subscription with postman - No Protocol Error

Tags: websocket, aws-appsync

I am using Postman to connect AWS Appsync **subscription** as per : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-websocket-client.html

with the below config:

[image]

{ "payload": { "errors": [ { "message": "NoProtocolError", "errorCode": 400 } ] }, "type": "connection_error" }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem occurs due to a missing header:-

Sec-WebSocket-Protocol = graphql-ws

Answer (score 1):

if you get this error in unity use this way;

```
using System.Net.WebSockets;
    
var webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
webSocket.Options.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
webSocket.Options.AddSubProtocol("graphql-ws");
```